# Using pyUno to write text into Libre/OpenOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-writer, uno, pyuno

I am trying to export some text from Python into a Libre/OpenOffice Writer document which I created according to [these](http://lucasmanual.com/mywiki/OpenOffice) instructions.

For example, using

```
cursor.setPropertyValue("CharHeight", 20)
cursor.setPropertyValue("CharWeight", 150)
document.Text.insertString(cursor, "This Is Heading One", 0)
```

I can make a line of text look like a heading, but it's just text and not an actual heading.  What property values do I have to modify to generate a heading line that's picked up for the TOC?

In general, where is the documentation for the properties, and how to navigate the Writer document in general?  I'm having a very hard time digging up anything at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this hasn't attracted much interest on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857919/using-pyuno-to-write-text-into-libre-openoffice-writer) :)  Neither has it in the forum over at LibreOffice.

Fortunately, the folks over at OpenOffice had a few good pointers, and a thread with above questions and more is [here](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=61222).  I'm going to keep discussing various aspects of document creation over there.